# Halo Dark Themes ProgressBar

Tags: android

I want to use android 4.2 Halo theme wiggets in my android 2.3.3 application.How can I do this. for example http://japan.widgetfolder.com/uploadfiles/japanwidgetfoldercom-1350092012/list-of-free-holo-themed-apps-for-android_32.jpg like in this picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the fantastic manual: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

> The Android platform provides a large collection of styles and themes
>   that you can use in your applications. You can find a reference of all
>   available styles in the R.style class. To use the styles listed here,
>   replace all underscores in the style name with a period. For example,
>   you can apply the Theme_NoTitleBar theme with
>   "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar".

Comment: What can I do when I want to use Android 4.2 Halo.Dark theme widgets on Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) to have the Holo Theme on pre HoneyComb devices.

Comment: Can you show me an example about how can I do this?

Comment: Clone the lib(or download it as a zip), import it in Eclipse, set your Theme to: `@style/Holo.Theme(.Light)`.